# How to validate the size of an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a model `Client` which contains an array field.
In the `client.rb` model I tried something like this :

```
field :menu_top
...
validates_length_of :menu_top, :maximum => 4
```

It seems to work but if I put more than 4 item in this array in the form, it sends me this =>

```
undefined method `admin_client_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fbc80a63cb0>:0x007fbc80b566b8>
Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <%= form_for [:admin, @client], :url => @post_form_path, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
2: <% if @client.errors.any? %>
3: <div class="alert-message block-message error">
4: <h2 class="dark-red"><%= pluralize(@client.errors.count, t(:error)) %> <%= t(:client_error) %>:</h2>
```

I don't understand why it doesn't render a form error.

Comment: Show the controller side method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your menu entries stored in the array and you are rendering the menu entries dynamically out of this array, right?

Now you have specified an menu entry in your array which isn't defined as such in the `routes.rb`. Try to run `rake routes` and check if `admin_client_path` is really there.

The error has nothing to do with your validation.

Comment: You are right, I check my code, and it was just a path error with a broken link.
Thanks !